# How can I get the expiration date of a certificate in a keychain from the command line?

Tags: command-line, keychain

I'm looking for a way to get the expiration date of a certificate from the command line. The certificate is in the default 'login' keychain and I know its name. How can I do this?

Comment: What for? In most cases, it seems like `security verify-cert`, potentially with the `-d` flag would work.

Comment: I want to know how much time a certificate has before it expires.

Comment: Just because? Is this going into an application of some sort or anything?

Comment: Yes, choosing between different similar certificates and signing using the one that is going to expire in the longest amount of time.

Comment: Gotcha. What language are you using for the app?

Comment: It's a python script but I was hoping to use a command line method in order to keep the script's requirements small. If there's a module that can do this then I'm open to using that too.

Comment: Maybe try stackoverflow?

Comment: Yeah, I think I will. I was originally thinking this was a mac specific question but maybe it makes more sense to ask there.

Comment: ...And it turns out I found the answer to my question there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command works:

```
security find-certificate -c "certificate name here" -p | openssl x509 -text | grep "Not After"
```

Answer (score 4):

GuyGizmo's answer doesn't seem to work with Xcode 10.1 tools on macOS 10.14.4. I pulled this way together after a few tries.

Since I was trying to find out when my developer code signing certificate expires from the command line, I could readily look at apps that I had signed:

```
codesign --display --verbose --extract-certificates /path/to/dir.app
```

That tells you a certain amount about the app, and extracts the embedded signing certificate (without its private key, so there's no need for passwords) to a file called `codesign0` in the current directory, in DER format. The other certificates in the chain of trust are extracted to `codesign1`, `codesign2` and so on, for as many as are needed. It's probably best to remove them once you've finished with them.

You can then use the OpenSSL command-line tool to get the expiry date:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in codesign0 -enddate -noout
```

Which prints a result like:

```
notAfter=June 8 10:37:33 2020 GMT
```

Another way to get the same information from the `codesign0` file, in a format that may be easier to parse with a programming language, is:

```
openssl asn1parse -in codesign0 -inform der | grep UTCTIME
```

That will show you the beginning and ending dates in [ASN.1 UTC time format](https://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node15.html), which is usually `YYMMDDhhmmssZ` in an Apple code signing certificate. Yes, the two-digit year does mean an ASN.1 UTC time wraps around every century.